# ordering the multiindex level manually

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table

I have a pivot table which has incorrect column order and i need the columns to be in order as i wish

The below code is for pivot table:

data_frame1 = pd.pivot_table(data_frame, index=['PC', 'Geo', 'Comp'], values=['Bill', 'Bill2'], columns=['Month'], fill_value=0)

**Code output**

```
               Bill1              Bill2
 Month       Jan    Feb        Jan    Feb     
PC Geo Comp
A  Ind  OP    1     1.28        1    1.28
B  US   OS    1     1.28        1    1.28
C  Can  OV    1     1.28        1    1.28
```

**Expected output**

```
                Bill2              Bill1
 Month       Jan    Feb        Jan    Feb     
PC Geo Comp
A  Ind  OP    1     1.28        1    1.28
B  US   OS    1     1.28        1    1.28
C  Can  OV    1     1.28        1    1.28
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df.reindex(['Bill2','Bill1'], axis=1, level=0)
print (df)
      Bill2       Bill1      
        Feb   Jan Month   Jan
A Ind     1  1.28     1  1.28
B US      1  1.28     1  1.28
C Can     1  1.28     1  1.28
```

Or if possible sorting in descending order:

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1, level=0, ascending=False)
```

Comment: bro i was using the below code but it was not working...
`new_order = ['Bill2', 'Bill1']`
`df = df.reindex([new_order, axis=1, level=0)`

Comment: @PraveenSnowy - Not undertand, you have to be more specific.

Comment: ..If **Bill1 & Bill2** are in level 1 then `df = df.reindex(['Bill2','Bill1'], axis=1, level=1)` is correct?

Comment: @PraveenSnowy - yes, exactly - `axis=1` means columns, `levels=1` means second level (in this answer it is first lelvel )